# Unable to add Android Virtual Device in Qt Creator?

Tags: android, qt, android-virtual-device

I am trying to develop an Android app with Qt and Qt Creator for the
first time on Windows 7. Everything worked quite well, but I am
running into one issue I cannot work around for Android.

I have followed all the getting started steps as outlined here
(http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/androidgs.html). This
includes installing the Android SDK, NDK, Ant and Java runtime. I have
also updated my JAVA_HOME environment variable as indicated.

Under the Android Preferences page in Qt Creator the SDK, NDK, Java and
Ant paths all seem correct and Qt Creator is able to pick up several
Android kits. However, when I try to add a new AVD, I get the following
trouble:

I can create new Android Virtual Device through Android Virtual Devices Manager, but when I create new AVD through Qt Creator, some mistakes happened.

This is the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com.android.sdkmanager.Main.promptForHardware(Main.java:1682)
      at com.android.sdkmanager.main.createAvd(Main.java:1447)
```

At this point I'm stuck and am not sure how to proceed. I imagine there
must be something simple that I am doing wrong.

Any help in resolving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you downloaded virtual device images when updating SDK?

Comment: yes, I have downloaded all the images of API 18, 19, 20